# How can I fix addressable in dependabot alert

Tags: rubygems

I am working in a sample application, I loaded it on github, after that there are found "Dependabot alerts" on Security. these alerts need versions update. How can I update these versions insight of github?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to this, so here is a solution without assurance.

First - what is **dependabot alert**?
Dependabot alerts are vulnerable dependencies detectors for your GitHub projects. GitHub automatically generates dependabot alerts for your codes.

As I know it finds/detects vulnerable dependencies. Like in react.js it will scan package.json and similar cases.

Then the alerts will show you the metrics or vulnerability (**CVSS base metrics**) of the dependencies.

Like: [Check Image shows the list of vulnerability and its impact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtvH7.png)

So, what you should do.
Just go to **Security tab** and click on alerts, then **Create Dependabot security update**

[Screenshot of Security tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm5oE.png)

For brief details please visit: https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-alerts/about-dependabot-alerts